# Copy document to another view and lock current document

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, domino-designer-eclipse

I am still new at Notes, so I'm still not familiar with every function. I will briefly explain my process.

I have a list of documents on "List" view. I want to copy all current documents to another view, let's say "Batch" as a new document, and lock flag all document on "List" view. I will edit the new document inside "Batch", and when I click save, this new document will save as new current documents, and for the old current document, it will remove to "old" view. So I can see new edit document and old document.

As for now, I found out [this link](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/fr/SSVRGU_9.0.1/basic/H_LOCK_METHOD_DOC.html) for lock flag but I do not know how to create for all documents

My question is, do I need to create a button on my view to copy all document to another view? How can I copy all document to a new view and save as new document? Can anyone advise any function that can I add to the process? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would approach this by first setting viewList.refresh to false: this stops the view index from being refreshed as you loop through the view, especially if you make an edit that changes something in the selection formula.

Loop through each document, with document.copy create the archive by setting the Form parameter.

At the end of the loop, and in the terminate event and/or error handler, set viewList.refresh back to true again.

This way you only need the lock the original document if you're going to edit it, and that's best done inside the loop for the shortest duration, rather than trying to lock all documents for the duration of the loop.  If you go down this route, also have a document unlock in the terminate event and/or error handler.

Theoretically the actions I've suggested terminate event and error handler don't need to be duplicated: just my cautious nature.

```
Function CopyDoc( docOld As NotesDocument, dbThis As NotesDatabase) As NotesDocument
    Dim docNew As NotesDocument
    On Error GoTo Handler

    Set docNew  = docOld.copyto(dbThis)
    Call docOld.lock()
    docOld.Form = "Archive"
    Call docOld.Save(True,True)
    Call docOld.unlock()
    'docNew Edits You Want To Make
    Call docNew.Save(True,True)
    Set CopyDoc = docNew
e:  Exit Function

Handler:
    Call docOld.unlock()
    'additional logging for diagnostics
    Resume e
End Function
```

Comment: I'll try this later. How about the changes in the current document. Can you suggest on how from copy document, replaced current document by copy document to make copy document live and old current document send to archive view? Thanks

Comment: Function CopyDoc( docOld As NotesDocument, dbThis As NotesDatabase) As Boolean
 On Error GoTo Handler
 
 Set docNew = docOld.copyto(dbThis)
 Call docOld.lock()
 docOld.Form = "Archive"
 Call docOld.Save(True,True)
 Call docOld.unlock()
 docNew.EditsYouWantToDo
 Call docNew.Save(True,True)
 Let CopyDoc = true
e: Exit Function
 
Handler:
 Call docOld.unlock()
 Let CopyDoc = False
 'additional logging for diagnostics
 Resume e
End Function

Comment: Oops: that was well formatted when I pasted it in.  Call the function inside your loop and stop if it returns false.

Comment: Ohh, sorry I didn't mention I'm using LotusScript. Really sorry, do you know how to use that in LotusScript? Thanks!

Comment: That is LotusScript: sorry the formatting is lost. Comments in Stack Trace loose the newline.

Comment: Oh, yeah, I'm a bit lost when I see that. Sorry. Btw, Thanks for your reply.

Comment: What I've done is improved the sample in the comment above and pasted it into the original answer so it's formatted nicely.  If the function's response "Is Nothing" then something went wrong.

Comment: Hi, can I ask. Where should I put the function? I just add a button on view and insert this function but nothing happened. Where should I insert the function supposedly? Sorry, I'm really not familiar with how LotusScript work. My apologies.

Comment: You need to write some LotusScript code that grabs the document(s) and a handle to the database and pass those to the function. I would also add at least one messagebox call to verify processed or abended.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191634/discussion-between-robert-howe-and-reinhaa).